# Pause or disable the page while doing ajax call Jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile, progress-bar, onpause

I am doing Ajax call which goes to server and get records back. Am showing progress bar on ajax and stops when done.

```
// Shows the loading bar when ajax call starts
$(document).ajaxStart(function() {
    $.mobile.loading('show');
});

// dismiss the loading bar when ajax call ends
$(document).ajaxStop(function() {
    $.mobile.loading('hide');
});
```

The progress bar shows but still I can edit the fields in the page. I don't want that to do. I want to have the page in pause state. I looked Jquery mobile API but nothing helped.

I am disabling each and every fields in ajax starts and enabling all on ajax ends. Is this the right approach ?

An example code snippet would help me

Comment: $('input,textarea').attr('disabled',''); , hide the form, place a div over it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a div/mask to the page to make it like disabled when the ajax starts and remove it when ajax ends. Try the following:

```
<style>
.mask{ background: #000; opacity: 0.5; position:fixed; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height:100%;}
</style>

<script>
$(document).ajaxStart(function() {
    $.mobile.loading('show');
    $('.mask').show();
});

$(document).ajaxStart(function() {
    $.mobile.loading('hide');
    $('.mask').hide();
});
</script>
```

and add HTML div with class `mask` to your HTML page like

```
<div class="mask"></div>
```

Comment: I works. But I know why it the mask didn't got applied for buttons and check-box in my page. The whole page got a dark Gray overlay and prevents click event as expected but buttons and check-box is active and responding for events too,

Comment: Adding zindex works .mask{ background: #000; z-index: 9; opacity: 0.5; position:fixed; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height:100%;}

Comment: Yes, z-index - i missed it :P